# How to cope with modifying an atomic value

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, gpgpu, c++-amp

I wanted to write a simple code that does some calculations based on input vectors of data. It should return just one value. I don't know how to achieve this. I wrote a simple test to check how it would work and I get a compilation error. Here is the code:

```
Float Subset::parallel_tests() 
{ 
float sum = 0.0f; 

concurrency::parallel_for_each(concurrency::extent<1>(121), [=, &sum] (concurrency::index<1> idx) restrict(amp) 
{ 
    sum += 0.2f; 
}); 

return sum; 
}
```

When I am trying to compile this code I get a following errors:

error C3590: 'sum': by-reference capture or 'this' capture is unsupported  if the lambda is amp restricted
error C3581: 'cci::Subset::parallel_tests::': unsupported type in amp restricted code

Comment: a) this code as written is probably not a good fit for AMP, as it inherently has a limitation of accessing a single memory location. If you need a gather operation consider using tiles and summing the tiles into smaller tiles... then summing those. b) are you accessing any class members in the lambda?

Comment: a) This is just a simple example of what I need to do. I want to have a sum of some values from a previously prepared vector. b) I am not accessing them as I know that whole class has to be compatible with C++Amp and it isn't. So... for now I need to check how to obtain a sum where every thread adds only some part to the result.

Comment: Use [tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873135.aspx) to sum parts of the vector, you might even be able to reuse the same kernel to do so... but you'll have to be careful about your stores.

Comment: But as far as I understand, I need to create an concurrency::array to store a few values (in my case I a tile would be a whole subset it would be just one value). Isn't there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Personally I would store into the first location of each tile. I would also use an `array_view` so I can ensure the data stays on the GPU for as long as possible. Then I would run the same kernel again with a different `extent` so that I only gather from those first locations and sum that into the first location on the array_view then just copy THAT back.

Comment: I analyzed your example and I don't know how your way can be faster than just making a one or even two-dimensional vector to store to output value.

Comment: That's why it's not an answer, there are many ways to achieve this.

Comment: Is it really that compilcated in C++Amp to return an atomic value computed by all threads?

Comment: Gather operations are a pain, but can be easily parallelized, however if you've already computed the value and just need to sum a fast loop on a CPU may be faster due to having a cache that doesn't take 600cycles to get to.

Comment: I am doing some massive image analysis. When I do computations on two different images (both on GPU, so the data is stored there), I need to compare them (also using GPU to avoid copying the image data back to CPU) so I need only one value (which is a correlation value of both images). That's why it HAS to be done on GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code does not compile is because `sum` is declared inside your class and not wrapped in an `array_view`. Essentially you are trying to access `this->sum` from the AMP restricted code. You need to use the following to wrap `sum` before passing it into the `parallel_for_each`, which should then use `avSum`.

```
int sum = 0;
array_view<int, 1> avSum(1, &sum);
```

You would also need to use an atomic operation to increment the value of `sum` across multiple threads, largely negating the parallelism afforded by the GPU. This is not the right approach.

**Reduction**

What I think you are trying to achieve is a reduction. You are trying to sum all of the values in an input array and return a single result. This is a well documented problem in GPU programming. NVidia has produced several white papers on it. [The C++ AMP Book](http://ampbook.codeplex.com/) also covers this in detail.

Here is the simplest possible implementation. It does not use tiling and is relatively inefficient but easy to understand. Each iteration of the `stride` loop adds successive elements of the array until the final result is in element 0. For an array of 8 elements:

```
stride = 4: a[0] += a[4]; a[1] += a[5]; a[2] += a[6]; a[3] += a[7]
stride = 2: a[0] += a[2]; a[1] += a[1];
```

The zero element now contains the total.

```
class SimpleReduction
{
public:
    int Reduce(accelerator_view& view, const std::vector<int>& source, 
        double& computeTime) const
    {
        assert(source.size() <= UINT_MAX);
        int elementCount = static_cast<int>(source.size());

        // Copy data
        array<int, 1> a(elementCount, source.cbegin(), source.cend(), view);
        std::vector<int> result(1);
        int tailResult = (elementCount % 2) ? source[elementCount - 1] : 0;
        array_view<int, 1> tailResultView(1, &tailResult);

        for (int stride = (elementCount / 2); stride > 0; stride /= 2)
        {
            parallel_for_each(view, extent<1>(stride), [=, &a] (index<1> idx)
                restrict(amp)
            {
                a[idx] += a[idx + stride];

                // If there are an odd number of elements then the 
                // first thread adds the last element.
                if ((idx[0] == 0) && (stride & 0x1) && (stride != 1))
                    tailResultView[idx] += a[stride - 1];
            });
        }

        // Only copy out the first element in the array as this 
        // contains the final answer.
        copy(a.section(0, 1), result.begin());

        tailResultView.synchronize();
        return result[0] + tailResult;
    }
};
```

You can tile this where each thread in the tile is responsible for producing a result for it's elements and then the results of all of the tiles are summed.

```
template <int TileSize>
class TiledReduction 
{
public:
    int Reduce(accelerator_view& view, const std::vector<int>& source, 
        double& computeTime) const
    {
        int elementCount = static_cast<int>(source.size());

        // Copy data
        array<int, 1> arr(elementCount, source.cbegin(), source.cend(), view);

        int result;
        computeTime = TimeFunc(view, [&]() 
        {
            while (elementCount >= TileSize)
            {
                extent<1> e(elementCount);
                array<int, 1> tmpArr(elementCount / TileSize);

                parallel_for_each(view, e.tile<TileSize>(), 
                    [=, &arr, &tmpArr] (tiled_index<TileSize> tidx) restrict(amp)
                {
                    //  For each tile do the reduction on the first thread of the tile.
                    //  This isn't expected to be very efficient as all the other
                    //  threads in the tile are idle.
                    if (tidx.local[0] == 0)
                    {
                        int tid = tidx.global[0];
                        int tempResult = arr[tid];
                        for (int i = 1; i < TileSize; ++i)
                            tempResult += arr[tid + i];

                        //  Take the result from each tile and create a new array. 
                        //  This will be used in the next iteration. Use temporary 
                        // array to avoid race condition.
                        tmpArr[tidx.tile[0]] = tempResult;
                    }
                });

                elementCount /= TileSize;
                std::swap(tmpArr, arr);
            }

            //  Copy the final results from each tile to the CPU and accumulate them 
            std::vector<int> partialResult(elementCount);
            copy(arr.section(0, elementCount), partialResult.begin());
            result = std::accumulate(partialResult.cbegin(), partialResult.cend(), 0);
        });
        return result;
    }
};
```

This is still NOT the most efficient solution as it does not have good memory access patterns. You can see further refinements on this on the book's Codeplex site.

Comment: Thanks, I already ordered your book and I am waiting for it to be sent to my country :). I am searching for the most efficent way of doing of what you called "a reduction". Could you give me an example of the most efficent code (and simplified if you were so kind :))?

Comment: I already found the examples from your book on the Internet :).

Comment: You want this one. http://ampbook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/CaseStudies/Reduction/CascadingUnrolledReduction.h. However I'd look at the one without unrolling first as it's easier to read http://ampbook.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/CaseStudies/Reduction/CascadingUnrolledReduction.h.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I started implementing the reduction. I begun with the simple reduction and I've encountered a problem. I don't want to pass a std::vector to the function but one or two concurrency::arrays.

I need to get information from source and sum everything parallely so that the value would be returned. How should I implement it?

The code in the naive version should look similarly to this:

```
float Subset::reduction_simple_1(const concurrency::array<float, 1>& source)
{
    assert(source.size() <= UINT_MAX);
//unsigned element_count = static_cast<unsigned>(source.size());

unsigned element_count = 121; 

assert(element_count != 0); // Cannot reduce an empty sequence.
    if (element_count == 1)
    {
         return source[0];
    }

    // Using array, as we mostly need just temporary memory to store
    // the algorithm state between iterations and in the end we have to copy
    // back only the first element.
    //concurrency::array<float, 1> a(element_count, source.begin());

    // Takes care of odd input elements – we could completely avoid tail sum
    // if we would require source to have even number of elements.
    float tail_sum = (element_count % 2) ? source[element_count - 1] : 0;
    concurrency::array_view<float, 1> av_tail_sum(1, &tail_sum);

    // Each thread reduces two elements.
    for (unsigned s = element_count / 2; s > 0; s /= 2)
    {
        concurrency::parallel_for_each(concurrency::extent<1>(s), [=, &a] (concurrency::index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
    {
        //get information from source, do some computations and store it in accumulator 
        accumulator[idx] = accumulator[idx] + accumulator[idx + s];

        // Reduce the tail in cases where the number of elements is odd.
        if ((idx[0] == s - 1) && (s & 0x1) && (s != 1))
        {
            av_tail_sum[0] += accumulator[s - 1];
        }
    });
}

// Copy the results back to CPU.
std::vector<float> result(1);
copy(accumulator.section(0, 1), result.begin());
av_tail_sum.synchronize();

return result[0] + tail_sum;
}
```

I need to implement the "accumulator" somehow but I don't know how.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.

Comment: OK, so from the beginning. In the sample from the book I found an example called "redution_sample_1". The method had one argument: a reference to std::vector. However this is not what I need. I need to pass a reference to one (or two) concurrency::array . I need to get some information from this data structure and when I'm done, I want to store the value in each thread and do a reduction so I return it as a value. The problem is that I don't know how to implement the accumulator that would store the partial results.

Comment: OK, I've run several reduction examples and all of them have the same problem: copying back data from GPU to CPU is very a time-consuming operation though it's the bottleneck. I found out that there is something called "staged arrays" but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: How do you know that the copy operation is the bottleneck? Remember AMP queues commands to the DMA buffer so that can be considered asynchronous requests. In the case of your example above the copy() is the first thing that will force the CPU process to actually wait for the AMP compute to finish. Are you sure you are timing the right thing? Copying one float should not take a long time.

Comment: So you really want to load in two arrays and then do a map to produce an intermediate set of data that is then reduced?

Comment: Maybe I will explain it in a pseudo-code in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
//The method should compute a correlation value of two images (which had already been copied to GPU memory) 

float Subset::compute_correlation(const concurrency::array<float, 1>& source1, const concurrency::array<float, 1>& source2) 
{
    float result; 
    float parameter_1; 
    float parameter_2; 
    . 
    . 
    . 
    float parameter_n; 
    parrallel_for_each(...) 
    { 
         //here do some computations using source1 and source2 
         parameter_1 = source1[idx] o source2[idx]; 
         .
         . 
         . 
         //I am computing every parameter in different way 
         parameter_n = source1[idx] o source2[idx]; 
    } 
    //compute the result based on the parameters 
    result = parameter_1 o parameter_2 o ... o parameter_n; 

    return result; 
}
```